# React 6 navigation and clicks not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Sorry to ask so many questions, but this only my second and 1/2 week working with React.

When I click on the following links, I can see the URL/URI change in the browser, but it does not seem to load the component(s). What am I missing?

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import NewComponent from "./new.component";
import ListComponent from "./list.component";

class NavComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { data: [] };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
          <nav className="navbar navbar-default">
            <div className="container-fluid">
              <div className="navbar-header">
                <a className="navbar-brand">Simple CRUD</a>
              </div>
              <div id="navbar" className="navbar-collapse">
                <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li>
                    <a href="#/">Coin Management</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#/add">Add Coin</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </nav>
          <Router>
            <Route path={"ListComponent"} component={ListComponent} />
          </Router>
          <Router>
            <Route path={"NewComponent"} component={NewComponent} />
          </Router>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default NavComponent;
```

I have tried to use Link to={"/"} and Link to={"/add"}, but the error will be -  Link should be used within the Router. I know that I am missing something simple.

I have also tried creating some onClick={"window.location.href=/add"} but I received the error - Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `string` type

The same error message when I use  onClick='{window.location.href="/add"}' - it does look like it is trying to do it.

Do I have to build a router group, like I did in Laravel? if so, then can you point me to some examples?

The following is the NewComponent that I want the app to navigate to or load in place of the ListComponent:

```
import React from "react";
import Axios from "axios";
import toastr from "toastr";
import $ from "jquery";
import bootstrap from "bootstrap";
import ListComponent from "./list.component";

class NewComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: null,
      price: null
    };
  }

  submitForm(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = $(event.target).serialize();
    toastr.clear();
    var isError = false;
    if (this.state.name === "") {
      toastr.error("Coin name must be filled!");
      isError = true;
    }
    if (this.state.price === 0 || this.state.price === "") {
      toastr.error("Coin price must be filled!");
      isError = true;
    }
    if (!isError) {
      toastr.info("Inserting new coin data...");
      Axios.post(
        "http://local.kronus:8001/v2018/ng6crud/api/put-coins/" +
          this.state.id +
          "/" +
          this.state.name +
          "/" +
          this.state.price,
        {
          id: this.state.id,
          name: this.state.name,
          price: this.state.price
        }
      )
        .then(function(response) {
          toastr.clear();
          window.location.href = "#/";
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          toastr.clear();
          toastr.error(error);
        });
    }
  }

  onCoinNameChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      id: this.state.id,
      name: e.target.value.trim(),
      price: this.state.price
    });
  }

  onCoinPriceChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      id: this.state.id,
      name: this.state.name,
      price: e.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form className="form-horizontal" onSubmit={this.submitForm.bind(this)}>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label className="control-label col-sm-2" htmlFor="coinEmail">
              Name :{" "}
            </label>
            <div className="col-sm-10">
              <input
                type="text"
                name="coinName"
                onChange={this.onCoinNameChange.bind(this)}
                id="coinName"
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Coin Name"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label className="control-label col-sm-2" htmlFor="coinPrice">
              Price :{" "}
            </label>
            <div className="col-sm-10">
              <input
                type="number"
                name="coinPrice"
                onChange={this.onCoinPriceChange.bind(this)}
                id="coinPrice"
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Coin Price"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <div className="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
              <button type="submit" className="btn btn-default">
                Save
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default NewComponent;
```

BTW, zero errors and a few warnings about bootstrap as being defined but never used

Once again, thanks in advance

Comment: You should only have one `Router` component at the top of your app, and your `Route` components should have a pathname as `path`, e.g. `/add`. You should also use the `Link` component for React Router navigation, not regular anchor tags. [Look at this for an example and compare to your code](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic).

Comment: No reason for these curly braces: `path={"ListComponent"}` Instead, just pass as strings: `path="ListComponent"`. Also, as @Tholle mentioned, only use one `<Router>` component. You can have deeply nested `<Route>` components if you want. But only one `<Router>`. Also, I see no benefit to changing the name from `BrowserRouter` to `Router`, but that's just my $.02.

Comment: Thank you @Tholle I am currently reading this article - https://medium.com/@pshrmn/a-simple-react-router-v4-tutorial-7f23ff27adf - which has this link - https://codesandbox.io/s/vVoQVk78 - as a result, I have created a main.component.js - while still using my nav.component.js to be present through out. While this working on the initial page, I am now having issues passing the props to the edit.component

Comment: @kronus To pass those props (other than those default from React Router) you need to use the `render` attribute rather than the `component`. So your Router comp for the NewComponent would be `<Router path='/add' render={ props => <NewComponent { ...props } foo={ this.state.foo } /> } />` should work. Where `foo` is the prop you want to pass and `...props` will be the props from React Router. Just to clarify, `{ ...props }` is the correct syntax. Only change the `foo.....` portion.

Comment: @kronus have a look at [Tyler McGinnis Explains Passing Props to Components With React Router](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-pass-props-to-components/)

Comment: Thanks @brandon-benefield - I was able to complete it - https://github.com/kronus/react-6-crud - I have a live example on my web site as well - http://kronusproductions.com/v2018/react-coins/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @tholle said in the comments, you should only have a single `Router` component wrapping the entirety of your app. Normally this is done at the top most component so something like

### index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import App from './components/App';
import './index.css';

ReactDOM.render(
  // here is where we are wrapping our app, <App /> in <BrowserRouter />
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

This is normally how a Create-React-App app is set up so whatever you are using YMMV. Just remember to wrap your top level component, usually `<App />` in the `<BrowserRouter />` or in your code `<Router />` component.

Now on to your `<Route />` components, curly braces are only necessary when we need to pass JS into our components attributes. In your example, `<Route path={"ListComponent"} component={ListComponent} />` the `path` attribute needs to be a URL, in relation to the home page, that will be responsible for rendering that component. So something more like `<Route path='./list' component={ ListComponent } />` is just fine. If you needed to pass a variable into path then you would use the curly braces like so `...path={ var + '/list' }...`.

Lastly, to get your `<NewComponent />` to load you need to `import { Link } from react-router-dom` and instead of using those anchor tags, use `<Link to='/add'>Links to the NewComponent component</Link>` and just make sure your Route component that renders the NewComponent's `path` attribute matches.

### Helpful links

[React Router 4 - Quickstart](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start)

Comment: Thanks once again @brandon-benefield - I was able to follow this example - https://codesandbox.io/s/vVoQVk78

Comment: BTW, the combination of your answer and @Tholle comments - one main component, which uses a navigation, as well as, myself updating to <BrowserRouter><App /></BrowserRouter> from things like  ReactDOM.render(<div><HeaderComponent /><Routes history={browserHistory} /><FooterComponent /></div>,document.getElementById('root'));, was what made it possible. Thank you sir

Answer (score 0):

- Change anchor tags to Link
- Change route path to url

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic

Follow react router example for better understanding

Comment: Thanks @hemanthvrm - I was able to follow this simple example - https://codesandbox.io/s/vVoQVk78 - See comments above - I was able to complete the CRUD proj - github.com/kronus/react-6-crud and I have a live example of my own - kronusproductions.com/v2018/react-coins